# VS 2015 RC DNX.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I installed visual studio 2015 rc and I am getting the error when I launch vs 2015 "VS 2015 RC  DNX.exe has stopped working .". Please tell me how to fix it. I have windows 7 sp1 .

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem with an example MVC 6 app.

I tracked my problem down to the dependency restore functionality when it tries to restore `EntityFramework.Commands (7.0.0-beta1)` ASP.Net Core 5.0 package.

Upgrading the package to the latest version (7.0.0-beta4 at this time) seems to have fixed the issue.

You *should* be able to do this while the dnx.exe error dialog is on screen but if you can't, just remove the dependency from the `package.json` file and save the file. At this point you can close the error dialog and it shouldn't reappear (unless **another** package is causing it!). Then use the NuGet package manager to re-add the package at the latest version number.